# Jquery insertAfter not working at certain screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to move a div to be under a certain div at 320px but it seems to be not working. http://jsfiddle.net/tr0uhpdn/ can someone point me to the right direction.

```
<div class="social">
    Social
</div>

<div class="after-news-sec">
    News
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 320) {
    $(".social").insertAfter(".after-news-sec");
  }
});
```

Comment: Include jQuery library in your fiddle!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/tr0uhpdn/3/

Comment: And in your project too, because with jQuery it works! [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tr0uhpdn/4/)

Comment: It works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

`insertAfter`is a `JQuery`feature. **Include `JQuery` into your project.**

Answer (score 0):

The function `insertAfter()` is a jQuery function. You need to use jQuery in your fiddle by:

[image]

Comment: I think the OP knows it is a jQuery function since he tagged with [tag:jQuery]

Comment: @CliffBurton Yes, but I guess he doesn't know how to include jQuery in the jsFiddle.